# Кастомизированная модель User, Django

Tags: django

Приветствую. Решил расширить базовую модель User для Django (1.9.7) (допустим, добавлением поля balance). Добавил `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` в `settings.py`.
Создал модель в models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, User
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    balance = models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=7, decimal_places=0, default=Decimal('0'))
```

Через встроенные формы авторизация и регистрация работают. Но если обратиться к `user.balance` ничего не выводит. Так же если попробовать удалить аккаунт из админки, то появляется ошибка:

> (1146, "Table 'mydatabase.project_myuser' doesn't exist").

Ну и поля `balance` в админке тоже нет.
Просьба помочь разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен внешний ключ на юзера, если вы наследуютесь от `AbstractBaseUser`
И вам не обязательно использовать этот абстрактный класс. Если хотите просто добавить поля к модели, наследуйтесь от `AbstractUser`
`AbstractBaseUser` нужен, если вы хотите полностью переопределить модель юзера

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=0, default=Decimal('0'))
```

И прописываете в `settings.py` переопределенную модель:
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = "<название приложения>.MyUser"`

> (1146, "Table 'mydatabase.project_myuser' doesn't exist")

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что таблицы нет в базе, скорее всего вы забыли сделать миграции. Сделайте их после того как поправите модель